# Java: cross sum of numbers from string input using substring() and length()

Tags: java, loops, substr, string-length

I am new in Java and I am supposed to create a cross sum only using substring() and length() methods, as well as Integer.parseint(). I am having hard times figuring out the solution for this exercise (Input: 123; Output: 6, (that is, 1+2+3 = 6). I think I am not understanding how the loop works. This is what I tried sofar:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Quersumme {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.out.println("Gebe Sie eine Zahl ein ---->  ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String zahlSumme;
        String subStr;
        int num;
        
        zahlSumme = scan.nextLine();
        subStr = zahlSumme.substring(0);
        num = Integer.parseInt(subStr);
        
        int sum = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
             sum += i; 
        }
        
        System.out.println("Die Summe ist: " + sum);
        
        scan.close();
        }

    }
```

Input: 123
Output: 7503

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * 
 */

public class QuerSumme3 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.out.println("Gebe Sie eine Zahl ein ---->  ");
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String zahlSumme;
        
        zahlSumme = scan.next();
        String substr;
        int sum = 0;
        
        substr = zahlSumme.substring(zahlSumme.length());
        
        for(int i = 0; i < substr.length(); i++) {
            i = Integer.parseInt(substr);
            sum += i;
        }
        
        System.out.println("Die Summe ist:----->" + sum);
    }

}
```

Input: 123
Output: 0

I not expecting to get here the solution of the problem, but only some advice what I am doing wrong and, above all, why the first attempt gives me back 7503. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Check out [`String#substring(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-), where you can specify a begining and an end index. With this, you should be able to extract each of your digits from your `String` to then sum. This should be done in a loop, where you extract each single digit in each loop iteration to then add to the sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second code you are using a for loop indexed with `i`

```
for(int i = 0; i < substr.length(); i++) {
```

but then you are updating this index with

```
i = Integer.parseInt(substr);
```

a better approach I feel is like

```
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String zahlSumme;
    
    zahlSumme = scan.next();
    int sum = 0;
    
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < zahlSumme.length() - 1; i++) {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(zahlSumme.substring(i, i + 1));
    }
    // add the last char
    sum += Integer.parseInt(zahlSumme.substring(i));
    System.out.println("Die Summe ist:----->" + sum);
```

}